# Eclipse PyDev - my build is clean yet I get Syntax Error at runtime

Tags: python, exception, pydev

Looks good here:

```
except socket.error, err:
     raise urllib2.URLError(err)
```

But gives this error at runtime:

```
    except Exception, e:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Using Python 3.3 and Eclipse 5.0

Any suggestions for me?  Do I need to reinstall the Interpreter?

Answer (score 3):

You are using the Python 2 `except` syntax. Instead, try

```
except socket.err as err:
    raise urllib2.URLError(err)
```

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) for more info about exceptions, errors, and how to handle them. You can also use the Python 3 syntax in Python 2.6 and 2.7, as it was back-ported.